# Is there a possibility to find unused functions in PhpStorm project (procedural)

Tags: function, phpstorm

I'm on a big procedural project existing since years and I want to clean up my code. I want to find all unused functions (not methods, it's a procedural project)

I'm using PhpStorm and only found a function to look for unused methods, but not working with functions.

I would like something like a list of results of unused functions never called in project.

Comment: Have you searched the PhpStorm plugin store?

Comment: Yes, and many forums

Answer (score 4):

A new feature in 2019.1 - the Unused Declarations inspection. You can choose what to look for.

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! But I don't find this Running Window, where did you find it please  ?

Comment: It's Code | Run Inspection by Name | Unused Declaration (PHP).